# Powershell Script Connect-AzureAD session on until Windows restarts, multiple windows

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have a Connect-AzureAD session enabled while we run other Powershell windows with AzureAD cmdlets?

I just wonder if this is possible to run a separate Powershell window where other commands can be executed later on using different variables.

An Example:

At the start day, you using Connect-AdAzure to connect with Azure, you are using your credentials,

in the middle of the day, your boss asks you to disable the account, then you open a separate Powershell window to disable the account you wanted to.

It is important to run it in separate windows, such as unattended scripts where you need to generate a certificate or secret code.

If you know what is webserver using PowerShell, I am trying to create a very similar connection, of course not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on your requirement there, if you want to keep separate windows for things like certificate signing or something, could you just open 2 windows at the start of the day, and leave them open, one for signing, and one for running azure commands?

Comment: @KG-DROID, Thank you for your answer. I'm planning to run a Task Scheduler rule and I want to skip the Connect-AzureAD in it, trying to find a way to avoid of asked for credentials. The Task scheduler will engage a certain script once a day if the expectation is met. The only challenge here is the AzureAd connection with prevents me to execute it correctly.  That is the reason it needs to be opened up in a different window, the Task Scheduler will try to open a new window every time it runs.

Comment: Ah ok, sounds like you want this in that case, user-less cert based auth:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: @KG-DROID you are 100% correct, but my question is this can be replaced by a process where you authenticate yourself until server/user restart/log out?

Comment: But you advised you didn't want to ask for credentials? If you are no longer authenticated after log out, then you would have to prompt for credentials again.